# PHP Require makes my page blank?

Tags: php, require

I have a reporting website that I created and I'm slowly adding functionality to it. I've just added a part where it is supposed to force a user to log in. It's really just to capture the users CorpID, I don't keep or record the password and it's not required.

Right now I have the login portion working. Then I'm trying to run a check to make sure that a user is logged in and if not to force them to log in. I am only doing this right now on the Admin page, which only I have access to. Here is how I've got it right now:

AdminPage.php:

```
<body>
    <?php
        require 'CheckLogin.php';
        include 'Menu.php';
    ?>
```

Other code for the page

CheckLogin.php:

```
<?php
    $Expiration = time() - (60*60*24*7);
    echo "You made it to here!";
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['UserName']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['UserName']))
        {
            setcookie("UserName",$_POST['UserName'],$Expiration);
        }
        else   
        {
            echo "<script>location.href='LoginForm.php'</script>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(isset($_POST['UserName']))
        {
            setcookie("UserName",$_POST['UserName'],$Expiration);
        }
        else
        {
            setcookie("UserName",$_COOKIE['UserName'],$Expiration);
        }        
    }
?>
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the Menu.php

```
<?php
    $AdminUsers = include 'AdminUsernames.php';
    if(isset($_COOKIE['UserName']) && in_array($_COOKIE['UserName'],$AdminUsers,TRUE))
    {
        $user = 'Admin';
    }
    else
    {
        $user = 'User';
    }
    //echo "<BR>"; print_r($_COOKIE['UserName']);
    //echo "<BR>"; print_r($AdminUsers);
?>
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix" id="menu">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="AdvancedSearch.php?PageName=AdvancedSearch">Report Builder</a></li>
            <li><a href="OPR Reports.php">OPCEN Reports</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="ReportPage.php?PageName=OPR_COEI">New COEI OPR Report</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ReportPage.php?PageName=OPR_OSP">New OSP OPR Report</a></li>                    
                    <li><a href="ReportPage.php?PageName=EOJ">EOJ Report</a></li>
                    <li><a href="MaterialTrackingReport.php?PageName=MaterialTracking">Material Tracking</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ReportPage.php?PageName=VendorMaterial">Vendor Material Tracking</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://mafinfwwapv01/Reports_MDAT/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/PMDB/CAF2 Tracker">CAF2 Tracker</a></li>
                    <li><a href="JIMReport.php?PageName=JIMReport">JIM Report</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CAFII Reports</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="minHeight"><a href="ReportPage.php?PageName=MaterialReceived">Material Received Job Not Started</a></li>
                    <li class="minHeight"><a href="ReportPage.php?PageName=CAF2Tracker">CAF2 Tracker New Test</a></li>
                    <?php 
                        include 'DBConn.php';
                        $data = $conn->prepare('SELECT Id, QName, SSRSName from pmdb.QDefs where QSrc = 2 AND IsActive = 1 order by QName');
                        $data->execute();
                        $result = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        foreach ($result as $q)
                        {
                            echo '<li class="minHeight"><a href="http://mafinfwwapv01/Reports_MDAT/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/PMDB/' . str_replace(' ', '+', $q['SSRSName']) . '" target="_blank">' . $q['QName'] . '</a></li>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Invoicing/Closing</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="ReportPage.php?PageName=NonVarassetInvoices">Non-Varasset Invoices</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">ENG Reports</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="ReportPage.php?PageName=ApprovedProjects">Approved Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ReportPage.php?PageName=ApprovedProjects_PrevDay">Approved Projects Previous Day</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ReportPage.php?PageName=M6Action">M6Action</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php
                if($user == 'Admin')
                {
                    include 'AdminMenu.php';
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

It's really just a standard menu and has been working fine till I added the `require` for the `CheckLogin.php` page.

All I get is a blank page when I have this `require` in the `AdminPage.php`. I don't get the `echo` I don't get the menu or anything.

What am I doing wrong? This isn't the first time that I've used the `require`, but it is the first time that it results in a blank page.

I do know that I have the expiration set to last week, I'm trying to force a re-login.

Comment: There's most likely a fatal error somewhere.  Check your PHP error log.

Comment: show what's your menu.php code. CheckLogin.php looks fine

Comment: You are setting cookies after flushing response

Comment: At the very, VERY top of your file add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` But if I had to guess I'd say your issue is as Mohsen described: you are trying to set cookies after flushing the page has started displaying data.

Comment: Suggest you take out the echo, as well as adding error_reporting(E_ALL).

Comment: @Jhecht I take out the `echo`, but still get a blank page. I'll see about getting the error logs.

Comment: @Brad Okay, where are the PHP error log files? I thought they'd be in the same directory as PHP, but I'm not seeing them.

Comment: @Mike Depends on where you configured them to be.  Run `phpinfo();` in a script... that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Brad perfect, I should have thought of that. However, the error log has nothing in it from today. Last entry was from 7/12

Comment: Just put this in the top of your script before any requires and includes...

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Holy crap! I'm an idiot! I didn't put the full path of the page it should have been `require 'Helper/CheckLogin.php';`

Comment: @Mike , Glad you found the issue. Probably best if you either put  your comment as an answer or delete your question.

Comment: @Doug You win, put that in an answer and I'll call it good. Thanks to all sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: @Mike It's not stupidity.  We all make such mistakes.  ~15 years ago I said I would give up coding after spending 12+ hours trying to track down a misplaced semicolon, which PHP at the time insisted was on Line #-2147483648.  Of course, I'm still coding.  :-D

Comment: @Brad I seem to have a lot of those moments! Just glad I haven't been kicked off here for showing it from time to time. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in your script before any includes or requires.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Doug's suggestion from above I found the error. In using the `require` I did not use the full path for the file and so it could not be opened. What that line should look like is:

```
require 'Helper/LoginCheck.php';
```